# Formik reset value on change (Select)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

The problem I'm facing now is that I don't know how to reset a value of a select when the other Select input changes.

**Here is a little bit more context**: I have 2 Select Inputs, one for states and the other one for cities (this Select changes when you select a state in order to make a request and get the cities that belongs to the state chosen. So, when you choose a state and a city everything is ok but, when you choose a different state, console shows next error

`` Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `Saltillo` for the select (name="city") component. Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''. ``

My idea is reset City value when the State select changes to avoid that issue. I'm learning formik so I don't know how to handle this or if it is a different way to do it.

```
React.useEffect( () => {
    getAllStates();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect( () => {
    getAllCities(formik.values.state);
  }, [formik.values.state])
```

Comment: Can you try to be more clear on the problem? What is ``select`` and ``state select`` plus what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: ok sure, I have 2 selects one is for states and the second one is for cities. So when you choose a state, the other select (cities) is populate with the cities that belong to the state chosen. The problem is that when I choose a state for the second time I got the error "Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value..." What I want to do is reset the cities value when the state changes to avoid that warning. Am I clear now?